# Hacer fflush(stdout) sin hacer include

Tags: c, stdout

¿Cómo se declara `stdout` en código de C? Quiero definir esa variable para poder hacer lo siguiente, pero sin usar el preprocesador `#include`:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Pude averiguar que es de tipo `FILE*`, además pude ver el prototipo de la función `FILE`, aunque no sé si esto es suficiente.

> Desde **/usr/include/bits/types/FILE.h**

```
struct _IO_FILE;
typedef struct _IO_FILE FILE;
FILE *stdout;
```

Pienso que solo con el prototipo de `FILE` no alcanza y sería necesario declarar las estructuras completas.

Comment: Para que quieres hacer eso? Pasando de la duda, estoy bastante seguro de que no
basta solo con declarar `FILE *stdout` y ya funciona.

Comment: @Pablochaches Es que quise compilarlo con un compilador que no soporta `#include`... Ahora pude ver que tampoco soporta `extern` y tampoco soporta `const`, creo que usaré otro.

Comment: Que compilador es ese?

Comment: @Pablochaches Se llama `mzcc`, lo encontré en _GitHub_ luego de buscar compiladores, estoy buscando más. https://github.com/jserv/MazuCC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para solucionarlo hay que hacer uso de `extern`... En este caso es así:

```
typedef struct _IO_FILE FILE;
extern FILE *stdout;
```

Al hacer `fflush` hace que el cursor esté siempre al final de la línea en la consola.

También se puede usar `extern` con `printf` y `fflush`.

Código completo:

```
extern int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...);

typedef struct _IO_FILE FILE;
extern FILE *stdout;

extern int fflush (FILE *__stream);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    for(int i=0;i<1000000;++i){
        printf("\r%i",i);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Lamentablemente el compilado estático da error, pero al menos funciona en el compilado dinámico:

```
gcc -static ./main.c -o ./s6
```

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/../lib64/libc.a(dl-reloc-static-pie.o): in function '_dl_relocate_static_pie':
> (.text+0x1a): undefined reference to '_DYNAMIC'
> /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x39): undefined reference to '_DYNAMIC'
> /usr/bin/ld: ./s6: hidden symbol '_DYNAMIC' isn't defined
> /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @Trauma Sin el `extern` compila pero al momento de ejecutarlo me tira `Segmentation fault`.

Comment: Raro. Todas las funciones son `extern` por defecto, por decirlo de alguna manera. Bueno, retiro lo dicho :-)

Comment: @Trauma Le hice un depurado con `gdb`, me sale esto, `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7e4933b in ?? () from /lib64/libc.so.6`... A mí lo que en verdad me gustaría es, declararlas pero sin el uso de `extern`, me imagino que eso hace que lea las funciones desde la carpeta `/usr/include`. Para poder declararlas tendría que tener el código completo de las estructuras.

Comment: Las variables no las puedes declarar sin el `extern`. Lo de las funciones ya te digo que me extraña ... pero nunca he probado a hacer esas cosas tan raras (omitir los `#include`) que tu haces :-)

Comment: @Trauma Es que quiero compilarlo en un compilador alternativo, ahora encontré otro compilador en _GitHub_. https://github.com/Fedjmike/mini-c/blob/master/tests/triangular.c Veo que no acepta `for` pero sí `while`.